# Given $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)=0$, does a $g$ exist such that $g(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_{n-1})=x_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Given $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)=0$, is it true that there exists a function $g$ such that $g(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_{n-1})=x_n$ ? If so, how could I go about proving it for the general case?

If not, what would be the broadest additional given that would make it true, i.e. the definition which would be true for the largest set of possible functions. For example, If I changed the statement to "given a ***linear*** function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)=0$" it is fairly straightforward to show that there exists a function $g$ such that $g(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_{n-1})=x_n$, but restricting the given function to *only* linear functions would be a pretty exclusive given.

Comment: you are essentially looking at the Implicit Function Theorem. It requires your $f$ to be well-behaved, so there are plenty of counterexamples you can find by just choosing $f$ to be non-smooth.

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to find this satisfactory, but a function is simply a relation between two sets such that any element of the first set is related to exactly one element from the second. Thus you can simply define $g$ to be the function that associates $(x_1,x_2,x_3...,x_{n-1})$ with $x_n$. That's about as broad a scope as you can get

Answer (score 2):

You need to add assumptions about the regularity (continuous, differentiable, etc) of $g$, otherwise you can get "weird" stuff: for example, if $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1=0$, then you can have $g(x)=h(x)\sqrt{1-x^2}$ where $h(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb Q$ and $h(x)=-1$ otherwise.

If this example is not weird and you are ok with $g$ being any kind of function, then the answer is almost always yes:

1. assume that for a given $(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$, the equation $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$ has a finite number of solutions $x_n$. Then you can define $g(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1})$ as the smallest solution. (You can change for any arbitrary rule)
2. If, for some $(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$, the equation $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$ has infinitely many solutions $x_n$, you may need the Axiom of Choice.